# How to move images to a different directory using Linux Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library

I am now trying to build a script that opens, rotates, resizes and saves several images contained in the images directory (running the `pwd` command gives the message `/home/student-01-052f372bc989/images`). The images contained in the images directory are of the format TIFF, have a resolution of 192x192 pixel and are rotated 90° anti-clockwise. The script must turn these images in the following formats:

1. .jpeg format
2. Image resolution 128x128 pixels
3. Should be straight

and save the modified images in the /opt/icons directory

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

Image_dir = '/home/student-01-052f372bc989/images'
imagedir = os.chdir(Image_dir)
new_dir = '/opt/icons'

for pic in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   if pic.endswith(".tiff"):
      img = Image.open(pic)
      new_img = img.resize((128,128)).rotate(270)
      newName = pic.replace(".tiff", ".jpeg")
      newdir = os.chdir(new_dir)
      new_img.save(newName, "JPEG")
      imagedir = os.chdir(Image_dir)
```

The code has no issue when I run it, but when I run the `ls /opt/icons` command to check if the modified images were copied to the directory, the images are not yet there.

The script is currently located in the `/home/student-01-052f372bc989/images` directory.

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: `shutil.move` takes two required parameters, but you only provide one. That should lead to an error. But anyway, why not save directly to the final path?

Comment: you mean like so:

Comment: for pic in pic_list:
    if pic.endswith(".tiff"):
        img = Image.open(pic)
        new_img = img.resize((128,128)).rotate(90)
        newName = pic.replace(".tiff", ".jpeg")
        new_img.save(newName)
        shutil.copy(newName, new_dir)

Comment: You are making life difficult for yourself! Rather than carry around long paths and faff around with directory separators, just `os.chdir()` to where your images live and glob them without a path. Then process them and save from PIL straight to the output directory and forget about saving in the wrong place and then moving them.

Comment: i made some modifications to the code and now it works perfectly when i run it on my windows pc but for some reason it runs but it does not save the images to the desired directory when i run the script it in linux

Answer (score 0):

So... with a bit of digging, i did manage to find an easier way to do the script

the code is as follows:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

old_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/images/'
new_path = '/opt/icons/'

for image in os.listdir(old_path):
        if '.' not in image[0]:
                img = Image.open(old_path + image)
                img.rotate(-90).resize((128, 128)).convert("RGB").save(new_path + image.split('.')[0], 'jpeg')
                img.close()
```